# HTTP post request error when trying to submit a form

Tags: java, angular, typescript, crud, httpservice

I've created a web application which creates football clubs and generates football matches
One function of it is when the user enters a random date on the GUI, the program should display all the matches played in that day.
For that I've created a form in my HTML file and using HTTP post request I want to send data to the my back end which is in another project (2 different ports)
localhost:4000-Angular GUI
localhost:8082-Java Spring Boot application (back-end)

Here is my code for the date check section!

----HTML file-----

```
<div id="dateContainer"><form #datePost="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(datePost.value)" >
<input type="text" name="date" ngModel placeholder="12/12/2012">
<button type="submit">Find</button>
</form>
</div>
```

-----Ts file----

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import{HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({

  selector: 'app-date',

  templateUrl: './date.component.html',

  styleUrls: ['./date.component.css']

})
export class DateComponent implements OnInit {

  onSubmit(data){

    this.http.post('http://localhost:8082/dateReq',data)

    .subscribe((result)=>{

      console.warn("result",result)

    })
  
  }
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

-----Java-----

```
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")

@GetMapping("/dateReq")

public ArrayList<String> getDates(){

    return PremiereLeagueManager.dateCheck;

}
```

When I enter a date in my GUI and click on find button I get these errors on my console

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8082/dateReq' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
:8082/dateReq:1 

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
core.js:5967 

ERROR HttpErrorResponse
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:5967
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the HTML-code as well as the error message(s) as text, not as image.

Comment: Turing85 It is CORS issue, no need for HTML code

Comment: @Masood can you help me please

Comment: @kavx I wish I could, but I don't know anything about Java. I was facing same problem with PHP.

Comment: Temporary solution for testing purposes you can install chrome extension MOESIF. This extension will allow to bypass CORS and make sure it's turned off while surfing other websites.

Comment: @Masood I tried it but didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have in Java a GetMapping and in Angular you use http.post?Get request don't have parameters,also.
Try to change in your ts file:

onSubmit(data){

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:8082/dateReq',data)

.subscribe((result)=>{

  console.warn("result",result)

})
```

}

and in java:

```
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")

@PostMapping("/dateReq")

public ArrayList<String> getDates(){

    return PremiereLeagueManager.dateCheck;

}
```

Also, I highly recommend you to use reactive forms because they are better, you can see details here :https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score -1):

you have a `@GetMapping` and as you are doing a post I think you need to import `@PostMapping`